# SQL filter to find recurring product names with varying statuses

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to select distinct products that are on file as "recurring" or "on file" for customers.

```
select a.customer_id,
      a.type -- reccuring/on file,
      b.name as product_name,
from table.a as a
join table.c as c on c.id = a.c_id
join table.b as b on b.id = c.b_id
where a.current_state <> 'canceled'
order by 1
```

my output looks like:

```
id/type/product_name 
<br> 111 on_file someProduct
<br> 111 recurring someOtherProduct
<br> 112 on_file someProduct
<br> 112 recurring someProduct
```

The end goal is to only select customers that have the same product name with a type that is both on_file and recurring. I have tried to rank them, but even though they have the same name the have different product ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need the below query

```
    Select id, product_name, 
     count(distinct type) from
    Table where type in
     ('on_file', 'recurring') group by id, 
     Product_name
     having 
    count(distinct type)=2
```

Comment: that was very helpful and quite simple, thank you for the quick reply, Himanshu